# Get all the totals of each customer by customer location

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to list total of sales by branch name and the location of store;

```
Ex Data Set,
Desc,Sales
Alex Vancouver west, 1000,
Amy Vancouver east, 1000,
Andy Vancouver north, 1000,
Alex Coq east, 2000,
Amy Coq west, 2000,
Andy Cog south, 2000,
```

Currently I have

```
SELECT SUM(Sales) AS Sales,'Vancouver' AS Location
FROM dbo.sales
WHERE DESC LIKE '%Vancouver%';
```

But I want my result set to be

```
Vancouver,3000
Coq,6000
```

I don't want a single set of results but instead a result set that matches my predetermined locations i.e. ('Vancouver,'Coq',...)

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `SUM()`.

Comment: SELECT  SUM(Sales) AS Sales,'Vancouver' AS Locattion
FROM dbo.sales
WHERE SD LIKE '%Vancouver%';

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I only want to grab totals out of a predetermined arrray ie ('Vancouver,'Coq',...) but have them in the same result set

Comment: @dalek I hope that my question makes sense I dont want a single set of results but instead a result set that matches my predetermined locations  ie ('Vancouver,'Coq',...)

Comment: `SD LIKE '%city1%' OR SD LIKE '%city2%' ...`

Comment: just gives me a sum of the two wild cards @tonypdmtr

Comment: You still need `GROUP BY SD` as @GordonLinoff said above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VALUES` to make a derived table with the location names and search strings, left join the sales to it and do the aggregation.

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(s.sales), 0) sales,
       l.display location
       FROM (VALUES (1,
                     'Vancouver',
                     '%Vancouver%'),
                    (2,
                     'Coq',
                     '%Coq%') l (id,
                                 display,
                                 search)
            LEFT JOIN sales s
                      ON s.sd LIKE l.search
       GROUP BY l.id;
```

---

Edit:

Having the separate ID and search string is not strictly necessary but offers greater flexibility.

- The ID allows two locations with the same name but different ID to be grouped by distinctively.
- Having the search string being extra allows it to differ from the location name with just '%' concatenated to its ends.

If you don't need that flexibility, you can reduce the derived table to just the location names:

```
SELECT coalesce(sum(s.sales), 0) sales,
       l.display location
       FROM (VALUES ('Vancouver'),
                    ('Coq')) l (display)
            LEFT JOIN sales s
                      ON s.sd LIKE concat('%', l.display, '%')
       GROUP BY l.display;
```

Comment: what is 1.display location, and 1.search strings doing there are they necessary, sales s and s.sales what are these referring to ? @stickybit

Comment: @dontay: They're not strictly necessary but offer greater flexibility. See the edit.